# after onclick (which will call a function), it keep loading and cannot detect keypress

Tags: javascript, onclick

i am new in javascript, I am quite confuse to the following problem:

Before i click the button, keypress can be detected and result in alert
However, after i click the button, the page keeps loading and no longer detect my keypress anymore, I would like to ask why will it happen? What wrong in my code?(Note that: even i use 2 diff functions for two printing, same problem exist)

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeypress = function(cde) {
        cde = cde || window.cde;
        alert ("some key pressed");
    }
    function abc(tester) {          
        if (tester == 0){
            document.writeln("<button onClick=\"abc(1);\" >To T1</button>")
            document.writeln("tester0")
        }
        if (tester == 1){
            document.writeln("tester1")
        }
    }
    abc(0);         
</script>
```

<---------------------------------------------------------------->

After using Maraca code(problem still exist):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeypress = function(cde) {
        cde = cde || window.cde;
        alert ('some key pressed');
    }
    var tester = 0;
    function switchTester() {          

        var b = document.getElementById('switch-btn');
        b.innerHTML = 'To T' + tester;
        tester = 1 - tester;
        if (tester==0)document.writeln('a list of html content A');
        if (tester==1)document.writeln('B a list of html content B');
    }       
    document.body.innerHTML='';        
</script>
<button id="switch-btn" onClick="switchTester();">To T1</button>
```

<---------------------------------------------------------------->

Thz Maraca again, his script help the switching of html fixed content, but what if the content has some variable? Like score/weather etc?

Maraca Code:

```
<script>    
    document.onkeypress = function(cde) {
        cde = cde || window.cde;
        alert ('some key pressed');
    }

    var state = 0;
    function toggle() {
        document.getElementById('toggle-btn').innerHTML = 'switch to state ' + state;
        var t = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-content');
        t[state].style.display = 'none';
        state = 1 - state;
        t[state].style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
<div class="toggle-content">
    <h1>default content</h1>
    <p>bla bla bla</p>
</div>
<div class="toggle-content" style="display:none">
    <h1>other content</h1>
    <p>whatever</p>
</div>
<button id="toggle-btn" onclick="toggle()">switch to state 1</button
```

>

Comment: Do you have the script at the bottom of your page? After all of your html?

Comment: I just try the script in the part of <body> in html

Comment: this usually happens because there was an error, did you try to press F12 works in most browsers and then look what it says in the console after reproducing the error, and there are semicolons missing

Comment: the 3 statements in the if, there `;` is missing, and here a hint because you say you are beginner: you can define Strings with single and double quotes, if you use double quotes everywhere in html, then it is easier to use single quotes in javascript, because you won't have to escape the double quotes then e.g. `'...onclick="abc(1);"...'`

Comment: Do not use `document.write`. It flushes the document flow. If you open DevTools and inspect your actual DOM after clicking the button, you will find your html was all gone, including your `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thz Leo, so what should i do if i want to print a list of html content out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(New answer after information was added.) Here is how you can implement a toggle button which also switches the content:

http://jsfiddle.net/sjq5ts5q/ (key events are only registered if the frame displaying the content has the focus)

```
<script>    
    document.onkeypress = function(cde) {
        cde = cde || window.cde;
        alert ('some key pressed');
    }

    var state = 0;
    function toggle() {
        document.getElementById('toggle-btn').innerHTML = 'switch to state ' + state;
        var t = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-content');
        t[state].style.display = 'none';
        state = 1 - state;
        t[state].style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
<div class="toggle-content">
    <h1>default content</h1>
    <p>bla bla bla</p>
</div>
<div class="toggle-content" style="display:none">
    <h1>other content</h1>
    <p>whatever</p>
</div>
<button id="toggle-btn" onclick="toggle()">switch to state 1</button>
```

(Old answer.) I think what you want to do is a toggle button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeypress = function(cde) {
        cde = cde || window.cde;
        alert ('some key pressed');
    }
    var tester = 0;
    function switchTester() {          
        var b = document.getElementById('switch-btn');
        b.innerHTML = 'To T' + tester;
        tester = 1 - tester;
        // if (tester == 0) do whatever you want to
    }        
</script>

<button id="switch-btn" onClick="switchTester();">To T1</button>
```

Comment: Oh Thz for your reply, infact, I am doing a switcher, which print out 2 diff html content, but your code cannot do so(I have edited my post, to show yr code)

Comment: @Question-erXDD added example, js-fiddle to prove it works ;-)

Comment: Thz for your reply again, however, what should i do if the content of html is changed in time? As what u have written is for fixed html content, while  document.writeln(x) can output the variable string which is not fixed. Thus, I would like to ask how to do it on javascript variable(like a score of game after click the button)

Comment: @Question-erXDD you will have to dynamically replace innerHTML as it is shown with the text of the button. The code probably will become ugly and a lot less readable... but it's just how it is, although you can make it easier for you by encapsuling every "component" in a function call with some parameters, then the code will become readable again

Comment: Reli thz for your reply, how to replace my innerHTML with a switch function. For example, I have a timer, and after click the button , it can go to the timmer page. And when I click the button again, it changes back to the content page?    OR    there is a count down function for every click, and when you switch to another page, it can show the variable of the count down value

Comment: @Question-erXDD use just one div for the content `<div id="content">` and replace its content with `document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = ...`